# How to identify the Node JS instance in Azure?

Tags: node.js, azure, express, cron, azure-web-app-service

I've NodeJS app deployed in Azure 'Web App for Containers' with few CRON jobs. When CRON jobs runs, the load increases leading to auto-scale by Azure.
The problem in here is; when autoscale happens, I believe new instances are created which causes the CRON jobs to initialize and run individually on each instance. But I want this CRON job to be running only one (aka; in 1 instance alone). Was thinking, if i could identity the instances somehow, then can restrict this CRON jobs to 1st instance alone. Can you suggest me how to do this (or) any other better ways to handle this case?

Comment: Have you tried the singleton pattern to solve your problem?

Comment: @JasonPan I’m pretty new to this area, could you please share any reference links that I can look and try

Comment: What is your new instances, new Object ?

Comment: You can use a lease on a blob to control singleton behavior. This is how the WebJobs sdk works.

Comment: Thanks guys, i'm going to try it out and get back with results.

Comment: @msg Has your problem been solved, is there any progress?

Comment: @msg If you have already solved it, you can post your answer to help more forum users.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. By default, WebJobs scale with the webapp.
As Jason mentioned singleton can work in your case.To share more details on how it works.

You can create a Settings.job file that contains the JSON data { "is_singleton": true }. This forces Azure to only run one instance of the WebJob, even if there are multiple instances of the associated web app. Note that this can be a useful technique for scheduled jobs.

Just to highlight the difference, Continuous jobs -Runs on all instances that the web app runs on. You can optionally restrict the WebJob to a single instance (singleton), whereas the Triggered jobs- Runs on a single instance that Azure selects for load balancing.

As mentioned above, to set a continuous job as singleton during deployment (without the need for the REST API) you can simply create a file called settings.job with the content: { "is_singleton": true } and put it at the root of the (specific) WebJob directory.
Kindly check this [document](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API#set-a-continuous-job-as-singleton) for the sample.